# onchange of DOM in Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom, onchange

```
var nameInput = document.createElement("input");
nameInput.type = "text";
nameInput.className = "loop_input";
nameInput.id = "nameAddress"+validLoadedEmails;
nameInput.value = data[0];
nameInput.onchange = editAddressHidden(validLoadedEmails);
```

it seems that when creating the element. It will already go to the editAddressHidden function and not when there's a change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your current code:

`nameInput.onchange = editAddressHidden(validLoadedEmails);`

You can think of this as saying "handle the `onchange` event of `nameInput` with whatever's returned from my `editAddressHidden` function". But that's not right (in this instance), as you want to handle the `onchange` event with the `editAddressHidden` function itself.

So wrap it up in an anonymous function:

```
nameInput.onchange = function(){ editAddressHidden(validLoadedEmails) };
```

Now every time the `onchange` event fires, it will invoke your function, and this will in turn call the `editAddressHidden` function.

Comment: Thank you! Creating input DOM is inside a loop and it seems that when I code

nameInput.onchange = function(){ editAddressHidden(nameInput.id) };

it returns the last namInput.id found in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
nameInput.onchange = function(){ editAddressHidden(validLoadedEmails) };
```

Because you call `editAddressHidden` function and assign returned value as input's change handler, that is not what you wanted.

Comment: Always good to explain **why** it works, rather than just **what** works. Otherwise the OP isn't going to learn